# Surface laptop 2 Sound issue on ubuntu

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, 22.04, surface

I have installed Ubuntu on my SL2, and everything is working except my audio. When I connect my headphones with the headphone jack. The headphones are detected, but it comes from the Sl2 speakers instead of the headphones when I play a sound.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: When you don't connect headphones, do the speakers work?

Comment: yeah the speakers work